# How to get text file from a relative path?

Tags: python

If I have a file directory like this:

```
-Proj
   - Proj.py
   - Directory
       - input.txt
```

and Proj.py wants to read from input.txt, how can I get to it? open() seems to only take an absolute address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relative paths are relative to the current working directory, which is usually the directory your shell was in when you invoked the python interpreter.

Use something like

```
import os
open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Directory', 'input.txt'))
```

Comment: This is the right answer, but it's better to use `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'Directory','input.txt')` as os.path.join will accept as many path components as you throw at it.